# cannot use git lfs command in GitHub actions

Tags: git, github, github-actions, git-lfs

[Giithub link](https://github.com/sovzzz/AKI-SERVER/actions/runs/5747334090)

In the first step `action-cached-lfs-checkout`, git lfs works.
But, in the second step composed by my self, it warns

> git: 'lfs' is not a git command. See 'git --help'. sync with an upstream git repo out of github. this repo has several lfs files.

Comment: Looks like your custom action runs inside a container. Make sure you install git-lfs in your container.